# create playbook which gathers managed hosts information and writes them to file on each hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

What I want to achieve with my playbook. On each hosts existing the following file

```
cat /tmp/host-info os_distribution= ip-address= sda-drive-size= sdb-drive-size=
```

Expected Result is

```
cat /tmp/host-info os_distribution= Centos ip-address= 192.168.0.23 sda-drive-size= 8000MB sdb-drive-size= 500MB
```

If one of them is not exists, value should be "DeviceNotExist" I have two hosts in my inventory (servera,serverb). On serverb not existing sdb drive. That make sense. in it's hosts info file should be sdb-drive-size=DeviceNotExist Playbook is here:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
     diska_size: "{{ ansible_devices['sda']['size'] }}"
     diskb_size: "{{ ansible_devices['sdb']['size'] }}"
     os: "{{ ansible_distribution }}"
     ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4['address'] }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Get disks
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/host-info
        regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
      with_items:
        - { regexp: '^sdb_disk_size =', line: 'sdb_disk_size = {{ diskb_size }}' }
        - { regexp: '^sda_disk_size =', line: 'sda_disk_size = {{ diska_size }}' }
        - { regexp: '^os_distribution =', line: 'os_distribution = {{ os }}' }
        - { regexp: '^ ip-address =', line: ' ip-address = {{ ip }}' }
    - name: ip address info  is not exist
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/host-info
        regexp: "^ip-address ="
        line: "ip-address = DeviceNotExist"
      when: ansible_default_ipv4['address'] is not defined
    - name: sda-drive is not exist
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/host-info
        regexp: "^sda_disk_size ="
        line: "sda_disk_size = DeviceNotExist"
      when: ansible_devices['sda'] is not defined
    - name: sdb disk is not exist
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/host-info
        regexp: "^sdb_disk_size ="
        line: "sdb_disk_size = DeviceNotExist"
      when: ansible_devices['sdb'] is not defined
```

It is working only for servera, But serverb is not getting any value on host

```
$ ansible-playbook hw-info6.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [serverb] 
ok: [servera]

TASK [Get disks] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
fatal: [serverb]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'sdb'"} 
changed: [servera] => (item={u'regexp': u'^sdb_disk_size =', u'line': u'sdb_disk_size = 1.00 GB'}) 
changed: [servera] => (item={u'regexp': u'^sda_disk_size =', u'line': u'sda_disk_size = 8.18 GB'}) 
changed: [servera] => (item={u'regexp': u'^os_distribution =', u'line': u'os_distribution = RedHat'}) 
changed: [servera] => (item={u'regexp': u'^ ip-address =', u'line': u' ip-address = 192.168.0.16'})

TASK [ip address info is not exist] ********************************************************************************************************************************************* 
skipping: [servera]

TASK [sda-drive is not exist] **************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
skipping: [servera]

TASK [sdb disk is not exist] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
skipping: [servera] to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/hw-info6.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
servera : ok=2 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0
serverb : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1
```

on managed hosts:

```
servera [ansible@servera ~]$ cat /tmp/host-info sda_disk_size = 8.18 GB sdb_disk_size = 1.00 GB os_distribution = RedHat ip-address = 192.168.0.16

serverb [ansible@serverb ~]$ cat /tmp/host-info sda_disk_size = sdb_disk_size = os_distribution = ip-address = 1- It is not working for serverb. Can you assist to solve this issue. 2- How can I convert GB to MB Regards,
```

Tags

Answer (score 0):

How about a `template` instead of `lineinfile`?

Example template file `host-info.j2`:

```
os_distribution= {{ ansible_distribution }} ip-address= {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{%- for disk in disks %}
{%- if disk in ansible_devices %}
 {{ disk }}-drive-size= {{ ansible_devices.get(disk).size }}
{%- else %}
 {{ disk }}-drive-size= deviceNotExists
{%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

With task:

```
- name: set host info
  hosts: info
  vars:
    disks:
      - vda
      - sda
      - sdb
  tasks:
    - name: set host info
      template:
        src: hostinfo.j2
        dest: /tmp/host-info
```

Output:

```
ubuntu@info1:~$ cat /tmp/host-info 
os_distribution= Ubuntu ip-address= 192.168.64.2 vda-drive-size= 5.00 GB sda-drive-size= deviceNotExists sdb-drive-size= deviceNotExists
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. How can I put conditions, in case device is not exists.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. How can I put conditions, in case device is not exists. e.g. On serverb no sdb drive. So,shouldbe  sdb_disk_size = deviceNotExists on host-info file

Comment: I modified the example to do that.

Comment: Andy, need your advice. How can I convert GiB into MiB. When I write the following getting error: sda_disk_size = {{ value.size*1024|pow(3))|round|int }}

Comment: There is a `human_to_bytes` filter which you probably need to run it through first. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#human-to-bytes. Something like: `(value.size | human_to_bytes) * 1024 * 1024 | round | int`